# Rails: error while installing rubyracer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, therubyracer

I am running 'bundle install' on my linode server. But not able to install cause of rubyracer. Bundle install output is:

```
Installing therubyracer (0.11.0) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
--with-pthreadlib
--without-pthreadlib
--enable-debug
--disable-debug
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/build.rb:50:in `build_with_rubygem_libv8': undefined local variable or method `libv8_include_flags' for main:Object (NameError)
from extconf.rb:20:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.11.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Actually gem rubyracer is installed but version is 0.11.4. I just don't know why it is not taking this version and accepting only 0.11.0.

Also how to install 0.11.0. When i run the command given in error "gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.0'", it fails to execute and gives:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
--with-pthreadlib
--without-pthreadlib
--enable-debug
--disable-debug
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/build.rb:50:in    `build_with_rubygem_libv8': undefined local variable or method `libv8_include_flags' for    main:Object (NameError)
from extconf.rb:20:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-    0.11.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0/ext/v8/gem_make.out
```

Can anybody here help? searched lot on stack and git but none of the given solutions working.

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem "paperclip"
gem 'mysql2'
gem "devise"
group :assets do
 gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end


gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'libv8', '3.11.8.4', :platform => :ruby
gem 'therubyracer', '0.11.0', :platforms => :ruby
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'
```

Comment: On which platform Linux or windows? Which OS are you using?

Comment: @SumitMunot linux. OS is ubuntu 12

Comment: Can you please post your gemfile here?

Comment: Ok try to include gem 'execjs' in your gemfile and run bundle update command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was face the same problem on ubuntu:

After some experimentation I was able to confirm that '`gem install therubyracer --pre`' on the command line worked okay, but telling bundler to use the `--pre` option didn't work:

```
bundle config build.therubyracer --pre
```

I don't know if that was because the gem was being pulled in via a dependency and not by an explicit 'gem' line in the Gemfile.  I was unable to fix this even after extensive Googling, but since 0.11 seems to be only a few hours old I decided to try reverting to the previous `0.10` version by adding:

```
gem 'therubyracer', '=0.10'
```

before the use of the gem that depended on it.  This forced bundler to pick the earlier version and it installed like a charm.  Hopefully `someone will fix 0.11` soon enough.

After looking at the issues for therubyracer on github this seems to be related to two different issues - one closed: https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/213 which suggests installing the libv8 gem first (or explicitly), and that causes a different error: https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/215 and that is not yet closed - the libv8 gem seems to have a corrupted binary in it for 64-bit targets.  The only solution appears to be to build libv8 from source or do like I did and back up to 0.11beta8 or earlier (someone says `0.11beta8` works).  Until then I suggest you watch the 215 issue on Github and await a fix.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999070/cant-install-therubyracer-in-arch-linux-64, Please refer

Comment: hey, gem install therubyracer --pre is not working here. gives error: Error installing therubyracer:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: Specify the version of gem in your gemfile, also install dependencies of 'therubracer' gem on your system.

Comment: U mean i should install libv8 and modify gemfile to 'gem 'therubyracer', :require => 'v8', :platforms => :ruby' instead of 'gem 'libv8', '3.11.8.4', :platform => :ruby
gem 'therubyracer', '0.11.0', :platforms => :ruby'?

Comment: did it but same error. It is continuously giving "An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.11.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.0'` succeeds before bundling."

Comment: Do you specify the version **gem 'therubyracer', '=0.10'** in your gemfile.

Comment: Ok do you have rvm set up?

Comment: create new gemset in rvm. with using apporpriate ruby version run the command **rvm gemset create GEMSET_NAME** then again try to run bundle updated command

Comment: if it doesn't work then try **bundle update therubyracer libv8** or **$ gem uninstall libv8** and **$ gem install therubyracer**

Comment: hey not used rvm before. what u mean by 'rvm gemset create GEMSET_NAME'? should i run "rvm gemset create therubyracer"?

Comment: oh cool. The prob is solved i guess. It ran bundle install without error! but as am using unicorn, it is giving 'unicorn: unrecognized service' now on service unicorn restart. Is it related to this? do u know the solution on this?

Comment: No, rvm is for multiple ruby version manager so it create a new environment for your application in the form of gemset. You can give any name to your gem set. for example "new". After creation you can use it with command **rvm use 1.9.3(YOUR_RUBY_VERSION)@new(YOUR_GEMSET_NAME)**

Comment: ohk. cool at least on issue is solved. now have to look for unicorn. Hey, thanks a lot for great help. Good day!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to multiple libv8 versions.

Solution: uninstall libv8 and run ur bundle. 
Commands :

1) gem uninstall libv8
2) Bundle

Answer (score 0):

this happens due to some conflicts with the libv8 as well, although you can just assign a version to the rubyracer and it will be installed:

change the following in the gemfile:

gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.1'

and do bundle install

If this also doesn't solve the problem, there are some issues with the libv8. Install the following gems manually:

gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2' 
if it doesnt install then please install imagemagick via brew
gem install libv8 -v 3.11.8.17 -- --with-system-v8
change the following in the gemfile:
gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.1'

and then do bundle install.